# How to use command: command < text file in cmd batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, io-redirection

Please help me how to use command as "command < file.txt"
I don't know this command is used like. Give me a few examples.
Thanks!

Comment: There's some examples [here!](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) More examples [here too](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Comment: Please read the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how this site works! This is not a tutorial site, it is a community for asking and answering questions specific to programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> command.exe < file.txt

That command would redirect the contents of `file.txt` to `command.exe`.

For example, if `file.txt` contained `hello world`,  then `set /p var=<file.txt` would result with the contents of `file.txt` to be stored to `%var%`. 

A complete batch file script utilising command redirection would be:

```
@echo off
echo hello 1234 > doc.txt
set /p contents = < doc.txt
echo The contents of "doc.txt"="%contents%"
pause
exit
```

Here are some links that further explain command redirection:
[http://robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php](http://mirum.weebly.com/redirect.html?url=http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php&auto=yes)
[http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html](http://mirum.weebly.com/redirect.html?url=http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html&auto=yes)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php
Visit the above link to know more about redirecting output from CMD to text files